# Issues with UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "barcodeId") as! String

Tags: wkwebview, uipasteboard

Can anyone tell me why the copied data from user defaults is not passing the correct value? Below is my code, the weird part about all of this is outside of the app, when pasting on to notes or safari on the device. It does indeed past the correct data. NOTE: I've removed the test url

```
   let testURL =  ""
```

//  let barcodeData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "barcodeId") as! String

```
 var barcodeData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "barcodeId") as! String



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    load(urlString: testURL)
}

// MARK: Private function

func load(urlString string: String) {
    let url = URL(string: string)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView.load(request)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('RCPT_BARCODE').value = \(barcodeData)") {(result, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
    print(String(describing: result))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't seem to "save" the "barcodeId", try to save it in the UserDefaults instead of just printing it, in the callback of `evaluateJavaScript`. Also you load the "barcodeData" only on the construction of your viewController (top value variables are initialized on creation, as if they were initialized in the `.init`)

Comment: How would I save it programmatically? Newb here The data also paste from UIpastbaord outside the app, so it seems it is saving?

Comment: `UserDefaults.standard.set(result, forKey: "barcodeId")`

Comment: I did this at the top of the code?